# How to remove brick from failed Gluster peer?

Tags: glusterfs

I have a host that is damaged and is marked as `Disconnected` in the pool list. To remove the host and replace it I need to remove the brick.

Info of my bricks:

```
Volume Name: myvol
Type: Distributed-Replicate
Volume ID: ccfe4f42-9e5c-42b2-aa62-5f1cc236e346
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 2 x (2 + 1) = 6
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: app-dev-v-job-0001.mydomain:/data/glusterfs/volumes/app
Brick2: app-dev-v-job-0002.mydomain:/data/glusterfs/volumes/app
Brick3: app-dev-v-job-0003.mydomain:/data/glusterfs/volumes/app (arbiter)
Brick4: app-dev-v-task-0001.mydomain:/data/glusterfs/volumes/app
Brick5: app-dev-v-task-0002.mydomain:/data/glusterfs/volumes/app
Brick6: app-dev-v-task-0003.mydomain:/data/glusterfs/volumes/app (arbiter)
Options Reconfigured:
performance.client-io-threads: off
nfs.disable: on
transport.address-family: inet
```

The damaged brick is `app-dev-v-task-0002.mydomain:/data/glusterfs/volumes/app`

I run `gluster volume remove-brick myvol replica 3 app-dev-v-task-0002.mydomain:/data/glusterfs/volumes/app force`

But I get: volume remove-brick commit force: failed: number of bricks provided (1) is not valid. need at least 3 (or 3xN)

Does this mean I need to remove all the bricks?
Will that not delete/destroy all data?

Comment: Have you fixed this problem, I got stuck at this point as well.

Comment: Don't remember to tell you the truth. Sorry!