# Gluster: How to replace a brick in a dispersed volume?

Tags: glusterfs

I set up a 4+2 dispersed volume. It worked well so far.

```
gluster volume info
Volume Name: disperseVol
Type: Disperse
Volume ID: 35386b55-829c-4bac-bdba-609427269cf4
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1 x (4 + 2) = 6
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: 192.168.129.227:/mnt/gluster/disperseVol
Brick2: 192.168.130.4:/mnt/gluster/disperseVol
Brick3: 192.168.130.2:/mnt/gluster/disperseVol
Brick4: 192.168.129.2:/mnt/gluster/disperseVol
Brick5: 192.168.130.3:/mnt/gluster/disperseVol
Brick6: 192.168.129.218:/mnt/gluster/disperseVol
Options Reconfigured:
nfs.disable: on
transport.address-family: inet
storage.fips-mode-rchecksum: on
features.bitrot: on
features.scrub: Active
```

Now two host burned down an the two bricks are gone. The volume works still well, but I'm unable to replace the vanished bricks. I followed [the gluster docs](https://docs.gluster.org/en/main/Administrator-Guide/Managing-Volumes/#replace-brick) but

```
gluster volume replace-brick disperseVol \
   192.168.130.4:/mnt/gluster/disperseVol \
   192.168.130.6:/glusterPool/disperseVol commit force
```

gives an error

```
volume replace-brick: failed: Pre Validation failed on 192.168.130.6. brick: 192.168.130.4:/mnt/gluster/disperseVol does not exist in volume: disperseVol
```

There is just the same line in the logs, so I got no idea how to continue. [Here](https://serverfault.com/q/1090136/455544) is a similar case without a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the host 192.168.130.6 exactly for? It does not host a brick, as I can see in your config.

Comment: 192.168.130.6 is the replacement for 192.168.130.4.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you linked, they say that the `replace-brick` command is for specific cluster types only:

> NOTE: Replacing a brick using the `replace-brick` command in gluster is supported only for pure replicate or distributed-replicate volumes.

Your volume, on the other hand, is a *dispersed* one. So you'll have to do it the more complicated way by removing the faulty bricks, adding two new ones and starting the self-healing process.

Comment: While searching the web, I found [this page](http://www.whiteboardcoder.com/2023/04/glusterfs-replacing-server.html) and he replaced a brick in a dispersed volume with `replace-brick`. I will retry the remove+add+heal way. Thanks so far.

Comment: Ok, I tried to remove the vanished bricks and to add the new ones, but all these steps made it just worse. Finally, I lost the volume. Ok, no problem, there were no vital data on that volume but before I start over, I would like to walk through the desaster-recovery procedure to make sure, that I'm prepared for the next brick/host failure. Can someone please point me to the documentation, how to do that whith a disperesd volume? Thanks.